# OpenVPN mac (Sierra 10.12.2) installation doesn't work

Tags: openvpn

I'm with Sierra (10.12.2), trying to install OpenVPN client (openvpn-connect-2.0.18.203.dmg) and it seems to just stuck at "Running package scripts" stage.

I dug deeper and saw in the installer logs that it happens during the `postinstall` script.
Inside it, it's trying to run:

```
/Library/Frameworks/OpenVPN.framework/Versions/Current/bin/capicli -w 10 EnumProfiles
```

That causes `installd` process to hog the CPU to 150-200% and it just gets stuck. (The `capicli` process itself is at 0% CPU)

I have no idea what is `capicli`, I can just guess it's trying to check what profiles are already installed for the user.

I've tried to use `dtruss` to get some ideas but didn't see anything meaningful. Also tried to run with different flags hoping to see at least a hint of what is it suppose to be doing, but nothing...

Does anyone have any idea of what else can I do to understand where the problem is?

Comment: Just cut your losses and install [Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/). I've used several other OpenVPN clients over the last 8 years or so (including the official client package), and all of them had significant problems except for Viscosity, which "just works".

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly and looks like a matured product. They are probably well worth their 9$.

Comment: No prob, glad it's working well for you.